# BST Node Deletion Confusion [JaVa]

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've created a Binary Search Tree in JaVa. Unfortunately 'delete' function doesn't work. I will be really appreciated if you could take a look. Thanks in advance..

**Problem:** I can't inorder print the tree after I delete a node from it.

***Node:***

```
class Node {

//Properties
private Node left, right, parent;
private int key;

//Getters and Setters
public Node(int key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public int getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(int key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(Node left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(Node right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public Node getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Node parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

}
```

***Binary Search Tree:***

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

//Properties
private Node root;

//Getters and Setters
Node getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public void setRoot(Node root) {
    this.root = root;
}

//Search Method
public Node search(Node x, int k){
    if (x == null || k==x.getKey()){
        return x;
    }
    if (k<x.getKey()){
        return search(x.getLeft(), k);
    }
    else{
        return search(x.getRight(), k);
    }
}

//Insertion Method
public void insert(Node z) {
    Node y = null;
    Node x = getRoot();
    while (x != null) {
        y = x;
        if (z.getKey() < x.getKey()) {
            x = x.getLeft();
        } else {
            x = x.getRight();
        }
    }
    z.setParent(y);
    if (y == null) {
        setRoot(z);
    } else if (z.getKey() < y.getKey()) {
        y.setLeft(z);
    } else {
        y.setRight(z);
    }

}

//Printer Method
public void inorder(Node x) {

    if (x != null) {
        inorder(x.getLeft());
        System.out.print(x.getKey() + " ");
        inorder(x.getRight());
    }
}

//Transplant Method
public void transplant(Node u, Node v){
    if (u.getParent() == null){
        setRoot(v);
    }
    else if (u==u.getParent().getLeft()){
        u.getParent().setLeft(v);
    }
    else{
        u.getParent().setRight(v);
    }
    if (v!=null){
        v.setParent(u.getParent());
    }
}

//Deletion Method
public void delete(Node x) {
      if (x.getLeft() == null) {
          transplant(x, x.getRight());
      } else if (x.getRight() == null) {
          transplant(x, x.getLeft());
      } else {
          Node y = minimum(x.getRight());
          if (y.getParent() != x) {
              transplant(y, y.getRight());
              y.setRight(x.getRight());
              y.getRight().setParent(y);
          }
          transplant(x, y);
          y.setLeft(x.getLeft());
          y.getLeft().setParent(y);
      }
  }

//Maximum Finder
public Node maximum(Node x) {
    while (x.getRight() != null) {
        x = x.getRight();
    }
    return x;
}

//Minimum Finder
public Node minimum(Node x) {
    while (x.getLeft() != null) {
        x = x.getLeft();
    }
    return x;
}

//Example Tree Constructor
public void createBST(int[] a){

    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        Node nodeToBeAdded = new Node(a[i]);
        insert(nodeToBeAdded);
    }
    inorder(root);
}

}
```

***and a Test class:***

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //CREATION
    System.out.println("CREATION");
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

    int[] a = {54, 32, 76, 7, 44, 63, 99};

    tree.createBST(a);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("The root of the tree is: ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Maximum Node is: ");
    tree.inorder(tree.maximum(tree.getRoot()));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Minimum Node is: ");
    tree.inorder(tree.minimum(tree.getRoot()));
    System.out.println();


    //INSERTION
    System.out.println("INSERTION");
    tree.insert(new Node(25));
    tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());

    tree.insert(new Node(485));
    System.out.println();
    tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());

    tree.insert(new Node(12));
    System.out.println();
    tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());

    tree.insert(new Node(5));
    System.out.println();
    tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());

    tree.insert(new Node(9985));
    System.out.println();
    tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Maximum Node is: ");
    tree.inorder(tree.maximum(tree.getRoot()));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Minimum Node is: ");
    tree.inorder(tree.minimum(tree.getRoot()));
    System.out.println();

    //SEARCH
    System.out.println("SEARCH");
    tree.inorder(tree.search(tree.getRoot(), 32));
    System.out.println();


    //DELETION
    System.out.println("DELETION");
    tree.delete(new Node(5));
    tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());
}

}
```

Comment: why don't you use Hash/Tree-Map and implement custom BST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see you don't override equals/hashCode methods so you can't find Node(5) because you created new instance. If you change your code in Test.java:

```
tree.insert(new Node(12));
System.out.println();
tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());
//  Start changes
Node node5 = new Node(5);
tree.insert(node5);
System.out.println();
tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());
//  End changes
tree.insert(new Node(9985));
// -cut some code
//DELETION
System.out.println("DELETION");
tree.delete(node5);
System.out.println();
tree.inorder(tree.getRoot());
```

it will print result

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @BerkYılmaz if it's correct could you accept my answer(click the tick on left under the vote arrows.) or upvote?